# Bootstrap non-fluid IE7 layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I'm using [Bootstrap's non-responsive grid](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) to layout a data-entry form. Though the form looks perfect in Chrome, IE7 displays the form with extra "padding", which takes away from the vertical space available. My organization [still(!) uses IE7](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186863/justify-moving-beyond-ie7), so **I need help correcting the following issues**:

1. Why is the input not lining up with the label above it?
2. Why doesn't the row span the entire container?

[image: IE7 lays out the form with extra padding]

Relevant HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DS-11</title>
    <link href="http://10.20.17.226:7080/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="http://10.20.17.226:7080/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="frm_referral_ds11" action="frm_referral_ds11.process" method="post">
    <div class="row coral-background border-side">
        <div class="span12">
            <label for="p_mailing_address"><strong>8. Mailing Address:</strong> Line 1: (Street/RFD#, URB, or P.O. Box, Apt./Unit, In Care Of or Attn (<em>e.g. in Care of - Jane Doe, Apt # 100</em>))</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="p_mailing_address" id="p_mailing_address" class="span12" maxlength="200" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css:

```
input.span12 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
}

.coral-background {
    background-color: #FFD595;
}

.border-side {
    border-left: 3px #000 solid;
    border-right: 3px #000 solid;
}
```

Comment: When I say "padding", I'm not necessarily talking about CSS box model's "padding".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that the [result (jsfiddle.net)](http://jsfiddle.net/andreymir/TbpxX/embedded/result/) you are trying to achieve?

HTML:

```
<form id="frm_referral_ds11" action="frm_referral_ds11.process" method="post">
    <div class="row coral-background border-side span12">
        <label for="p_mailing_address"><strong>8. Mailing Address:</strong> Line 1: (Street/RFD#, URB, or P.O. Box, Apt./Unit, In Care Of or Attn (<em>e.g. in Care of - Jane Doe, Apt # 100</em>))</label>
        <input type="text" name="p_mailing_address" id="p_mailing_address" class="span12" maxlength="200" />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
 .coral-background {
    background-color: #FFD595;
}
.border-side {
    border-left: 3px #000 solid;
    border-right: 3px #000 solid;
}
```